# Azure function not sending message to Service Bus

Tags: azure-functions, .net-5

I wrote this Azure Function and I'm able to invoke from a http request:

```
    public static class ZendeskWebhookToServiceBus
    {
        [Function("ZendeskWebhookToServiceBus")]
        [return: ServiceBus("functions", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        public static string Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            return "{\"value\": 12345}";
        }
    }
```

The problem is that message will never hit Service Bus (no errors either). After a lot of tries I looked at the auto-generated function.json (that's actually called function.metadata in my machine) and what I observed is that the "Out biding" section seems wrong. I suppose type should be something like "servicebus" or maybe something like that.

```
    "bindings": [
      {
        "name": "req",
        "type": "HttpTrigger",
        "direction": "In",
        "authLevel": "Anonymous",
        "methods": [
          "get",
          "post"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "$return",
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "Out"
      }
    ]
```

I'm using .Net SDK 5.0.301 w/ runtime 5.0.7 and the following imports:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.0.3" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: Yes,the binding seems to be type of `ServiceBus` like      `{
        "name": "$return",
        "type": "ServiceBus",
        "direction": "Out",
        "queueOrTopicName": "functions",
        "connection": "ServiceBusConnection"
      }`. Try deleting the function and create a new function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are not using the right package for `ServiceBus` binding. You should use `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus` package for .net5 SDK for isolated function instead of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus`.

Once you use the right package you will see that functions.metatadata file will have correct bindings. For ex, for below code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Extensions
{
    public static class HttpInputServiceBusOutput
    {
        [Function("HttpInputServiceBusOutput")]
        [ServiceBusOutput("outputQueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        public static string Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("ServiceBusFunction");

            logger.LogInformation("Service Bus");

            var message = $"Output message created at {DateTime.Now}";
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

The generated binding is

```
{
    "name": "HttpInputServiceBusOutput",
    "scriptFile": "Extensions.dll",
    "entryPoint": "Extensions.HttpInputServiceBusOutput.Run",
    "language": "dotnet-isolated",
    "properties": {
      "IsCodeless": false
    },
    "bindings": [
      {
        "name": "req",
        "type": "HttpTrigger",
        "direction": "In",
        "authLevel": "Function",
        "methods": [
          "get",
          "post"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "$return",
        "type": "ServiceBus",
        "direction": "Out",
        "queueOrTopicName": "outputQueue",
        "connection": "ServiceBusConnection"
      }
    ]
 }
```

You can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#differences-with-net-class-library-functions) office documentation for further information.

[image]

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that I had to change the used Attribute from "ServiceBus" to "ServiceBusOutput" as show in @user1672994 example above.